# Eclipse plugin to detect jars only needed for Test classes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have 10 projects with each having 20 dependencies. Is there an Eclipse Plugin to detect jars only needed for Test classes?

This way I can exclude them from production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know such a plugin and static code analysis will only help you if you never use reflection or things like JDBC (which map Strings to Java types).

A good tool to clean the classpath is Maven. Maven (unlike Eclipse) keeps separate classpaths for the main code and unit tests. After migrating your build to Maven, simply set the scope of all dependencies to `test`.

Compile and the compiler will print the missing symbols. Remove the `<scope>` element for those and compile until Maven is happy.

Comment: The good thing is that we already use Maven as well. I will give it a try and let you know. Thank you!